# Templatized Object Pool in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, game, interface

I'm following [Robert Nystroms example](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html) to try and implement a decent object pool for my next couple of C++ based games. My version is templatized to allow arbitrary classes to be pooled.

I'm asking for input on two things:

1. The method names and interface design (both on the Pool and the iPoolable interface).
2. A slightly more concrete smell is that I'm adding two methods to the public interface of all "poolable" classes. Is there a way to make sure the `iPoolable` interface is only accessible to the Pool?

Any other tips and input would of course be greatly appreciated as well!

(Here's [all the code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DG3mAZpN), for proper syntax highlighting.)

```
#pragma once
#include <cassert>
#include <array>
#include "iPoolable.h"

//This class borrows liberally from Robert Nystroms excellent ObjectPool
    //http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html

template<class T, size_t POOL_SIZE = 32>
class Pool{ 
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<iPoolable, T>::value, "Type must implement iPoolable!");
    mutable iPoolable* _head = nullptr; //linked list of unused objects
    std::array<T, POOL_SIZE> _objects;
public:
    Pool(){             
        _head = &_objects[0];               
        for(size_t i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE - 1; ++i){ // Each object points to the next.   
            _objects[i].setNext(&_objects[i + 1]);          
        }       
        _objects[POOL_SIZE - 1].setNext(nullptr); // The last one terminates the list.      
    }
    void recycle(T* object) const noexcept {
        assert(object != nullptr);
        object->onReturnToPool(); //notify the object
        object->setNext(_head); //add the object to front of the list
        _head = object; 
    }
    T* getNext() const noexcept{
        assert(_head != nullptr); // Make sure the pool isn't exhausted.                
        T* nextObject = static_cast<T*>(_head); //get the head of the list
        _head = nextObject->getNext();  // Update the head of the list  
        nextObject->onTakenFromPool(); //notify the object
        return nextObject;
    }       
    template<typename Function>
    void apply(Function f) {        
        std::for_each(_objects.begin(), _objects.end(), f);     
    }   
    ~Pool(){
        //give objects a chance to clean up before being destroyed. (onReturnToPool is noexcept!)
        apply(std::mem_fn(&T::onReturnToPool));
    }
    size_t static constexpr size() noexcept { return POOL_SIZE; }   
};
```

(Not happy with `recycle()` or `getNext()`)

The `Pool` expects type `T` to implement the `iPoolable` interface.

```
#pragma once
class iPoolable{
public: 
    virtual iPoolable* getNext() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void setNext(iPoolable* next) noexcept = 0; 

    //Optional: release resource handles, stop timers, clean up.
    virtual void onReturnToPool() noexcept {}; 

    //Optional: re-aquire resources, start timers, re-initialize members. 
    virtual void onTakenFromPool() noexcept {}; 

    virtual ~iPoolable(){};
};
```

Again I'm looking for input on the interface. `setNext` and `getNext` might be too generic and collide with members in the derived classes. `onReturnToPool` / `onTakenFromPool` are overly verbose. What should I call them instead?

Implementing the interface should be trivial - either inherit from the concrete class `Poolable` (at the cost of an additional pointer member):

```
#pragma once
#include "iPoolable.h"
class Poolable : public iPoolable{
    iPoolable* _next = nullptr;
public: 
    void setNext(iPoolable* next) noexcept override{
        _next = next;
    }
    iPoolable* getNext() const noexcept override{
        return _next;
    }       
    virtual ~Poolable(){
        _next = nullptr;
    }   
};
```

Or avoid the cost of an additional pointer by implementing `iPoolable` manually in your class, and stuffing the pointer in a union with members we are already using:

```
template<class T = float>
class Vector2D : public iPoolable{
public:     
    union{ //anymous union
        struct{
            T x;
            T y;
        }; //struct of 2xfloat = 8 bytes        
        iPoolable* _next; //pointer = 8 bytes
    }; //union total = 8 bytes
    iPoolable* getNext() const noexcept override { return _next; }
    void setNext(iPoolable* next) noexcept override { _next = next; }

/* ... rest of Vector2D interface ...*/
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two major improvement you could do here.

### You don't need the object to be set up as a linked list.

Consider that you could have the following:

```
// gets the array index at which an object resides.
std::size_t get_index(T* object) const noexcept {
  return object - &_objects[0];
}
```

And you could rebuild the class in a much simpler way around it, and it gets rid of iPoolable entirely! want a `Pool<std::unique_ptr<int>>`? no problem!

### You are creating too many objects too soon.

```
std::array<T, POOL_SIZE> _objects;
```

This creates a bunch of problems:

1. T must have a default constructor
2. T's constructor get called for all objects as soon as the pool iscreated
3. T's destructor doesn't ever get called.
4. T basically can't use RAII semantics

the stl provides you with the super handy `std::aligned_storage` to deal with these situations, where you can in-place create and in-place delete object from safely.

Comment: Thanks for your input!

I'm not sure that I understand your first point - the linked list allows me to find the first *unused* object in the pool, with O(1)  lookup time. I see how your get_index work, but not how it provides an object that's ready to be (re)used?

Point 3: the std::array will in fact call the dtor of all objects when the pool is destroyed. ... right?

Comment: Point 4: The loss of RAII does bother me alot - my first attempt had a variadic forwarding method and allowed exceptions to escape, but like you say; the construction has already happened. So the user had to rely on setup/teardown methods for object (re-)initialization and it seemed to be more demanding than handing back objects in whatever-state to let the user reinit them. 

Definitely going to look up std::aligned_storage to maybe delay construction!

Comment: @ulfben, regarding destructors: yes, but not when you are done with the object...

Comment: @ulfben: regarding O(1), It's 100% possible to do this in O(1) and maintain a non-intrusive approach. A simple way of doing this is maintaining a std::stack of freed indces. If you want to be a bit fancier... I normally try to avoid tooting my own horn, but check out [my solution to the same problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174888/non-fragmenting-pool-allocator) for an example if you need inspiration